# How do you refund a transaction in Authorize.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authorize.net

I am just referring the docs of Authorize.net. I will soon be working on a Automated Recurring Billing application. The code seems to be pretty simple for this as the doc is very well written. However in the samples I can't find how to refund the transaction.

This is the link that I am referring to:

http://developer.authorize.net/downloads/samplecode/

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Was the support and community section offered in their developer center not sufficient?

Comment: Why are you here then? I see you have posted C# questions. Was the microsoft forum not sufficient?

Comment: That's fair. My thought was that you would find a far higher concentration of knowledgable Authorize.Net API users and questions/answers in their own developer center, which appears to have considerable traffic. Apparently I'm alone on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do refunds with the ARB API. It must be done either through the AIM API or the merchant control panel. If you use AIM set `x_type` to `CREDIT` instead of `AUTH_CAPTURE`.

Comment: Does there really need to be one? Did you really downvote that for that?

Comment: If the question says, "How do you refund a transaction in Authorize.net?", has a tag of C# and ASP.Net, and this is stackoverflow.com after all, and well-knowing that the "sample code" at AuthNet leaves much to be desired, then yes, I was expecting to see either some pseudocode steps or actual source here.

Comment: Downvotes are for when the answer is less than helpful. This didn't even really seem like an answer, but more of a, "Hey, don't trip over this," kind of response.

Comment: There question was "why can't I do refunds in ARB?". My answer explained why and how they could do it. No code necessary. The question-asker and others thought it was satisfactory. I don't know why you need to see code for an answer to be correct or good. Lots of answers here that are excellent contain not one bit of code.

Comment: But the question title is completely different than "why can't I do refunds in ARB?" If that's the question in the title, then your answer would make sense to me. Also, why did the person bother to mention C# and ASP.Net if they didn't want to see source code and a simple "you can't do that" type of response would do?

Comment: "If you use AIM set x_type to CREDIT instead of AUTH_CAPTURE" solved my problem too :) ty ^^